# iOS Swift detect keyboard events

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Can I somehow detect events from iOS keyboard?

I would like to detect this kind of events on the `UIViewController` which does not have `UITextField` or any sort of this kind of objects.

All I have are four circles that are `UIView` and I would like to paint them in different colour when the button on the keyboard is pressed.

[image]

Comment: If there is no texfield, how do you open the keyboard? Keyboard only opens for input events and texfield is one of the ways to take input. Textview maybe?

Comment: I totally forgot about that. Is possible to make some custom input view for TextField? So I can make TextField that will look like dots on picture?

Comment: You certainly can create a background view but I don't understand your requirement. If you don't need a textfield or a textview, then why do you expect keyboard events on the screen? What is the rationale of changing the colors with input events?

Comment: Imagine it is a PIN input controller. The user will enter four digit PIN which will be checked. So when the user enters a number the first circle goes to other colour and so on.

Comment: Use this `texfield.secureTextEntry = true`

Comment: OK I have to try this. It is possible to have two blue circles and two black circles on the Text Field? Is this kind of text manipulation possible?

Answer (score 16):

You are not having any object to take the input from the keyboard. To make the keyboard appear, you must have either UITextField or UITextView object in your view.

But here is the process to detect the keyboard events in your view controller. You can set observers on view controller for keyboard notifications.

To register for keyboard notification in swift 3, use write these lines in viewDidLoad() or viewWillAppear() method of your view controller

```
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyBoardWillShow(notification:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyBoardWillHide(notification:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
```

And  then implement two methods keyBoardWillHide(:) and keyBoardWillShow(:) method in your view controller

```
    func keyBoardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
            //handle appearing of keyboard here
    }


    func keyBoardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
              //handle dismiss of keyboard here
     }
```

Comment: Any idea how can make TextField like the one on the picture I posted?

Comment: If you want to show keyboard , you can create a UITextField object programmatically and make it first responder  when you want to show the  keyboard.

Comment: Vah jitubhai vahh.. su answer 6. thanx

Answer (score 12):

**Swift 4.2**

Register for events:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification , object:nil)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification , object:nil)
```

Selectors:

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
   let keyboardHeight = (notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue.height
   print(keyboardHeight)
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
   let keyboardHeight = (notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue.height
   print(keyboardHeight)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own View with keyboard handler

```
//Example
class CustomKeyInput: UIControl, UIKeyInput{
    //UIKeyInput
    public var hasText: Bool { return false }
    public func insertText(_ text: String){
        print(#function)
        print(text)
        print(text.characters.count)
    }
    public func deleteBackward(){
        print(#function)
    }

    //UIControl
    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {return true}
}


//Usage
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var keyView: CustomKeyInput!

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        keyView.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```