# Prevent TableView from reloading data when keyboard is dismissed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8

I currently have a table-view with a textfield acting as a search bar above it. I have the tableview set in interface builder to dismiss the keyboard onDrag. However, whenever I drag down the tableView reloads its data. How can I prevent this?

Comment: show us some code, where you are reloading the tableview

Answer (score 0):

You could use the keyboard events to enable and disable user interaction on the table, to do this you must register keyboard observers as said in the answer of this question by Jitendra Solanki: [iOS Swift detect keyboard events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43199794/ios-swift-detect-keyboard-events)

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyBoardWillShow(notification:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyBoardWillHide(notification:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
```

And use the callbacks functions to enable and disable the user interaction

```
func keyBoardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
            tableView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }


    func keyBoardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
              tableView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
     }
```

But instead ofthe keyboardWillHide, you could use your event of hidekeyboard to reactivate the user interaction.